# Choosing isolines from Matlab contour function

Tags: matlab, coordinates, contour

The Matlab contour function (and imcontour) plots isolines of different levels of a matrix.
I would like to know: How can I manipulate the output of this function in order to receive all the (x,y) coordinates of each contour, along with the level? 
How can I use the output [C,h] = contour(...)  to achieve the aforementioned task? Also, I am not interested in manipulating the underlying grid, which is a continuous function, **only extracting the relevant pixels which I see on the plot**.

Comment: "Difficult to work with" and "not straightforward" doesn't disqualify a solution.  Just go with it.  If you have problems, re-ask your question with the problems you are actually having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this function. It takes the output of the `contour` function, and returns a struct array as output. Each struct in the array represents one contour line. The struct has fields

- `v`, the value of the contour line
- `x`, the x coordinates of the points on the contour line
- `y`, the y coordinates of the points on the contour line

  function s = getcontourlines(c)

  ```
  sz = size(c,2);     % Size of the contour matrix c
  ii = 1;             % Index to keep track of current location
  jj = 1;             % Counter to keep track of # of contour lines

  while ii < sz       % While we haven't exhausted the array
      n = c(2,ii);    % How many points in this contour?
      s(jj).v = c(1,ii);        % Value of the contour
      s(jj).x = c(1,ii+1:ii+n); % X coordinates
      s(jj).y = c(2,ii+1:ii+n); % Y coordinates
      ii = ii + n + 1;          % Skip ahead to next contour line
      jj = jj + 1;              % Increment number of contours
  end
  ```

  end

You can use it like this:

```
>> [x,y] = ndgrid(linspace(-3,3,10));
>> z = exp(-x.^2 -y.^2);
>> c = contour(z);
>> s = getcontourlines(c);
>> plot(s(1).x, s(1).y, 'b', s(4).x, s(4).y, 'r', s(9).x, s(9).y, 'g')
```

Which will give this plot:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, the example along with the plot make everything very clear (-:

Comment: There is a typo in this line: `z = exp(-x.^2 -y,^2);` You probably would want to replace `,` with `.` here. Apart from that, I don't know how `#` and `%` used to look 4 years ago but now the text following `%` appears in grey color and seems decent or it could be just me!! 