# Separating one isoline from contour function

Tags: image, matlab, contour, topography

I used the contour function on an RGB image (after separating the three channels)
and now I want to treat each isoline separately.

How I can get each isoline information in a separate matrix?

I have 9 isolines and I want 9 matrix's.

I tried this one ([Choosing isolines from Matlab contour function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301626/choosing-isolines-from-matlab-contour-function)) and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the image (or a link to it) and the code you are working on?

Comment: HiA=imread(''); img=imcrop(A,[374.5 303 520 520]); red = img(:,:,1);
green = img(:,:,2); 
blue = img(:,:,3); [C,h] = contour(red,9); I used contour3 and contourf and contourc also, I tried this also:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301626/choosing-isolines-from-matlab-contour-function ;  This is the image : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzsfivX7CZg6REhWQThTVEtpbzQ/view?usp=sharing  ;

Comment: I can not provide you with an answer before next Saturday, nevertheless, the data you are looking for should be stored in the [ContourMatrix](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour-properties.html#prop_ContourMatrix). I'll be back Saturday, please, let me know if, in the meanwhile you solved the problem.

Comment: Instead of writing code and providing links  in the **comments**, **[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42026779/edit) your question** and include these details in it!

Comment: @il_raffa;Still waiting